# CRON unexpected EOF /bin/sh command not found

Tags: linux, shell, command-line, cron

On Cent OS Linux 7 I'm trying to run this cron job which generates a JSON file with the timestamp as filename.

```
timestamp=(date +%s) && php generate_json.php > $timestamp.json;
```

The problem is I get this error

> /bin/sh: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `)'

I thought maybe need to escape some characters, so tried escaping the brackets and get this response

> /bin/sh: +: command not found

So not sure where I'm going wrong here.

I'm not running the cron job as root so I'm not sure if this is a permissions issue if escaping the brackets resolved it. All I know is error for both.

Comment: Well I can run the commands so maybe no permissions issue. I searched for similar issues and the permissions suggestion came up which is why I brought it up. The issue is making it run as a cron job

Comment: Percent % is a special character for cron. Escape it with \%  I think you wanted `timestamp="$(date +\%s)"`

Comment: Yes, check the `crontab(5)` man page for details.

Comment: Should this not be `timestamp=$(date +%s)`?

Answer (score 0):

Please remember cron job has no path and no environment variables.

Assuming user name is `user_5`, Suggesting the following:

1. Create a script:

#### /home/user_5/cron_script.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
source /home/user_5/.bash_profile
timestamp=(date +%s) && php generate_json.php > $timestamp.json;
```

2. Create a crontab job

#### crontab -e

```
* * * * * /home/user_5/cron_script.sh
```

Expect to see your output every minute in `/home/user_5`